# RoslynPad: could not load file or assembly exception

Tags: .net-assembly, roslyn

I am using RoslynPad project to test how external plugins (Class libraries) could be used in the script.
I have created Class Library with a single class and method.
In roslynPad project i have added "plugin_demo" into RoslynHostReferences NamespaceDefault structure.
I have also added reference to plugin dll:

```
MetadataReference newref = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile("G:\\projects\\demos\\plugin_demo\\plugin_demo\\bin\\Debug\\plugin_demo.dll");
MetadataReferences = MetadataReferences.Add(newref);
```

Now i see that my new class is seen by diagnostics and autocomplition also works.
The code with a method call compiles fine.
But when i run it i get exception:
Could not load assembly or file. File not found.

I have copied plugin_demo.dll into directory where compiled roslynPad dll resides. Still no result.
I have checked that class library and roslynpad use the same .Code version.
What can be the problem?
What is correct way of adding assemblies to roslyn project?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem after debugging. The roslynPad project generates file nams_deps.json  when editor is launched. It must be deleted and after that the assembly is found.